# ocation of JavaMail Version 1.4.1 on weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using `javax.mail.*` . 
I was getting an `AuthenticationFailedException` when calling the`connect(host,username,password)` method. When i enabled debug for javamail i found out that it was using JavaMail version `1.4.1`. I have the code deployed on Weblogic 10.3. 
When i added `mail1-4.jar` which uses JavaMail Version `1.4ea` to the classpath it started working.

I am not able to find from which jar weblogic was picking up java mail version `1.4.1`. Any pointers?

Also what are the difference between java mail `1.4.1` and `1.4ea`. I was able to figure out the reason of difference in behavioir by decompiling the code. But still which one should be preferred?

P.S. I have posted the same on CodeRanch forum also.

Answer (score 0):

1.4.1 is newer.  You can find the list of changes [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/doc/release/CHANGES.txt).  (1.4ea is the same as 1.4)

Most likely it's this change that's causing the problem:

- do SMTP authentication if connect is called with username and password even if mail.smtp.auth is not set